# Using an intent to make a call

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I'm trying to make my code make a call, I have tried it this way:

```
    Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+number));
    phoneIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    if (checkPermission()) {
        startActivity(phoneIntent);
    }
```

But when I try to use it in my app, about 70% of the time it makes the call but then immediately hangs up before it had time to dial, couldn't really figure out what might be the problem.
Any suggestions ?
(edit) The function posted above is called from a broadcastreceiver , Could it be whats causing the call to disconnect? (I found another person with the same problem who also tried to make a call from a broadcast receiver)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check if

```
private boolean isTelephonyEnabled() {
    return this.getActivity().getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY);
}
```

than on action

```
if (isTelephonyEnabled()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:18009999999"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

Comment: I want my app to automatically make the call without me needing to press the dial button